# How can i create table row and column vertically

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted the following table to be diaplayed vertically.

```
<table id="news" class="table table-striped table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Phone</th>
          <th>City</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) 
        { ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <input type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td>
               <input type="email"/>
            </td>
            <td>
               <input type="number"/>
            </td>
            <td>
               <input type="text"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php
        }
        ?>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The Table will be displayed in below format
[image]

I want that to be displayed like the below format.

```
Row0 Name [input]
Row0 Email [input]
Row0 Phone [input]
Row0 City [input]

Row1 Name [input]
Row1 Email [input]
Row1 Phone [input]
Row1 City [input]

.
.

Row4 Name [input]
Row4 Email [input]
Row4 Phone [input]
Row4 City [input]
```

I want the html table to displayed like the above. Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a list? Either `<ul>` or `<ol>` and your cells will be `<li>`? Hope this helps!

Comment: I wanted to do it using tables. Is it not possible using tables alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want,

```html
<table id="news" class="table table-striped table-responsive">
    <tbody>
        <?php
        for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) 
        { ?>
        <tr>
        <td><b>row0</b></td>
           <th>Name</th>
            <td>
              <input type="text"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><b>row0</b></td>
            <th>Email</th>
             <td>
               <input type="email"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><b>row0</b></td>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <td>
               <input type="number"/>
            </td>            
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td><b>row0</b></td>
            <th>City</th>
            <td>
               <input type="number"/>
            </td>            
          </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>           
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You just need to think out of the box a bit

Comment: Yes this is what i wanted. But where can i pass row0,row1

Comment: I just followed the main HTML you posted it doesn't show how you pass the row. Any way I updated the answer just put your number variable between the `<td></td>` tags where I've put `row0`

Comment: If my answer full fill your need please mark it as the best answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can make them `display:block` but I'm not quite sure what effects this would have on table layout.

```
table#news td {display:block;}
```